# Displaying Google AdSense Advertisements only Twitter Visitors

Tags: php, twitter, preg-match, strpos, http-referer

I want to display my Google Adsense ads only when visitors come from Twitter. Currently I'm using this code this is working for Facebook and others but its not working on Twitter

```
    <?php
            $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            if (strpos($ref, 'twitter.com') != false) {?>
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    /* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
    google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    google_ad_width = xxx;
    google_ad_height = xxx;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
</div>
</div>

<?php }else{
  echo "";  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter redirects links via https://t.co
look for a t.co referer